# Функциональность и гибкость языка

Tags: java, c#, веб-программирование

Какой язык более гибок и функционален в использовании?

То есть на каком языке легче реализовывать задачи разного типа (десктопные приложения, мобильные, веб-скрипты, клиент-серверные приложения и прочее...).

На данный момент выбор стоит между C# и Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# и Java - это языки примерно одной весовой категории, и каких-то выдающихся преимуществ именно в их собственных средствах (а не в средствах сопутствующих фреймворков, библиотек и тд) у них друг перед другом нет. Более того, наличие или отсутствие тех или иных средств языка (в разумных пределах) не является определяющим фактором для разработки  на нем того или иного типа приложений. Тут гораздо большее значение играют другие аспекты. В частности, считается, что на C# удобнее разрабатывать десктопные приложения. Но это совсем не потому что в C# есть лямбда-функции, а в Java их нет (ну на самом деле уже есть), а потому что для C# есть достаточно удобный и современная технология WPF, а Java (могу ошибаться) ничего такого нет. При этом Java наверняка будет лучшим выбором, нежели C#, если вы вздумаете разрабатывать что-то под Android, поскольку сейчас этот язык де-факто стал стандартом разработки под эту платформу.

Иными словами, если вы выбираете между этими двумя языками, то озвученный вами критерий "какой язык более гибок и функционален в использовании" вообще не должен играть большой роли - они оба достаточно гибки и функциональны. Вам нужно отталкиваться от других критериев. В частности, от того, что и под какие платформы вы хотите писать